# Windows terminal/powershell path issue (/mnt is added)

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal

for years I was using bash as my daily terminal. Today I wanted to give a chance to Windows Terminal but I faced path issue right away.

I'm using NX monorepo in my project wihich is based on on react and strapi, develop commands are working fine with bash but when I run `nx run cms:develop` with Windows Terminal all  I get is

`/mnt/d/projects/[project_name]/apps/cms/node_modules/.bin/strapi: 12: node: not found`

As you can see, there is `/mnt` at the begining of path and I don't know why/how it's added and what are the steps to get it working "the right way"

part of `workspace.json`

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/nx/schemas/workspace-schema.json",
  "version": 2,
  "projects": {
    "cms": "apps/cms"
  }
}
```

`project.json` located in `D:[project_name]/apps/cms`

```json
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "projectType": "application",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/cms/src",
  "targets": {
    "serve": {
      "executor": "@nx-extend/strapi:serve",
      "options": {}
    },
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nx-extend/strapi:build",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/cms"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "production": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "tags": []
}
```

Thank for your help in advance

Comment: Windows uses  backslash for pathnames will linux uses forward slashes.  When harddrives are added in linux they are located in the folder /mnt.  You can get list of folders use ls -l mnt.  Driver can be mount with different formats like a Window Drive or a Linux Drive.

Comment: @jdweng But `/mnt` does not exist due the I'm not on Linux/Docker or having runing WSL. I'm runing terminal directly from project directory

[screenshot](https://ibb.co/1Zjp77t)

Comment: have you tried not using a relative path?

Comment: I replaced `apps/cms/src` with `apps\\cms\\src` and it works now. Also seems to work using Bash. Is there a way to force powershell to understand path with forward slash path ? All I found is [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1678786/is-there-a-way-to-make-powershell-use-forward-slashes-instead-of-backslashes-for)

Comment: You are running NX.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_technology